# Запрос в elasticsearch через spring data

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa

Начал изучать elasticsearch и пытаюсь создать запрос в эластиксерч через elasticsearch-spring-data.
Данные следующие :

```
List<Long> bookId;
Long authorId;
Timestamp from;
Timestamp to;
```

Нужно найти список книг по `List<Long> bookId`, у которых `автор = authorId` и книги выпущены с `from` до `to`.

То есть подставить в запрос список

```
List<Long> bookId where author_Id = authorId from ... to...
```

Как-то так... с помощью чего и как это можно осуществить?

Comment: `List<Long> bookId;` это что такое и к чему относится?

Comment: это id книг, нужно пройтись по каждому айди , найти совпадния, потом проверить у них authorId, и сравнить, что они вышли в нужный период (from to)

Answer (score 0):

Одна из ключевых фишек Spring Data * - создание запроса из правильно именованного метода. В вашем случае метод должен быть назван так:

```java
public interface BookRepository extends Repository<Book, Long>
  List<Book> findByAuthorIdAndBookIdInAndIssuedBetween(Long authorId, List<Long> bookIds, Timestamp from, Timestamp to);
```

Соответственно, возвращаемая сущность, которая мапится на индекс, должна иметь следующие поля:

```java
@Document(indexName="books")
public class Book {
  @Id
  Long bookId;
  Long authorId;
  Timestamp issued;
}
```

Если вы используете платную "Идею", то она самостоятельно подхватит ваш репозиторный интерфейс и при написании запроса будет подсказывать возможные варианты.

Примеры соотношения имён и генерируемых запросов можно посмотреть здесь: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.repositories